# Partial update to an index template

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch, is it possible to make a partial update to an index template?

For example, I tried changing only the default analyzer with the following (using Sense):

```
PUT /_template/testtemplate/_update
{
    "settings": {
        "index":{
            "analysis": {
               "analyzer": {
                  "default": {
                     "type": "whitespace"
                  }
               }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Bu that didn't work, I get an error that says `Invalid index name [_template], must not start with '_'`.

Do I have to pass the full template again using a PUT or there's some other way to do a partial update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partial updates only work for documents (and to some extent to mapping types), not for index templates. So, I confirm you'll need to store the full index template again and not only the small bit of it that you want to update.

As you can see in the source code for [`RestUpdateAction.java`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/fae494aa845bbb9e48797ac953ae5ec140c0e6eb/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/update/RestUpdateAction.java#L60), the `_update` REST endpoint expects an `{index}` name, a `{type}` name and an `{id}`. So in your example above, that endpoint thinks that `_template` is an index name and complains.

Similarly, in the REST endpoint for creating index templates, [`RestPutIndexTemplateAction.java`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/148265bd164cd5a614cd020fb480d5974f523d81/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/admin/indices/template/put/RestPutIndexTemplateAction.java#L35), you can see that the `_template` path doesn't support the `_update` endpoint at all.

Comment: I'm really new to ElasticSearch, thanks for the pointers to the code.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't hesitate if you have any questions ;-)